# Zend Framework - Same title for every controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, bootstrapping

How would I assign a page title once in the bootstrap (so I don't have to do it in each controller)? Is there a link that will point me in the right direction?

Is using the bootstrap the correct way?

I currently have this in each controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->title = 'Cut It Out';
}
```

layout.phtml has this:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
```

Comment: I would say your layout script is the place to do that.

Comment: I can just hardcode it but the title will eventually be coming from a database.

Comment: Then use a view helper, but the layout is still the place I'd do it.

Comment: I do refer to it in the layout.phtml (see update) but I don't know where I can set it so I only set it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a view helper for this to echo the title into your layout script in layouts/layout.phtml.

Create the file /application/views/helpers/SiteTitle.php :-

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_SiteTitle extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function siteTitle()
    {
        $siteTitle = getTitleFromDbSomehow();
        return $this->view->escape(siteTitle);
    }
}
```

Then in your layout head section you would have:-

```
<title><?php echo $this->siteTitle(); ?></title>
```

If you want it in the body somewhere:-

```
<h1><?php echo $this->siteTitle(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't how to create the helper :) You solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred method is to use a view helper:

In application/views/helpers/Title.php:

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_Title extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function title()
    {
        $title = 'cut it out'; // or from database

        return $this->view->escape($title);
    }
}
```

In your layout.phtml:

```
echo $this->title();
```

However, if you must use the Bootstrap (e.g. you want to override in a controller action):

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initTitle()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $view->title = 'Cut It Out';
    }

}
```

Comment: @rob Reading your book got me on the road to successfully using ZF. Thanks :)

Comment: I was gonna say! I have just finished the PDF. Must get the book.

Comment: Thanks. It's off-topic to the question, but also consider Keith Pope's book. I've not read it, but it has a good reputation and is more recent as it covers ZF 1.8+. For my book, the first few chapters are out of date due to Zend_Application, but the rest is still good.